# how to put link or other characters in print php

Tags: php, printing

I  am using include php in header file to get this to get information from content.php
  In content,php you have

```
  <?php $mainlevel4header = "WHAT'S DIFFERENT? ADDWEBTOUR";?>
```

I put the following in index.php

```
<h4 class="total-solution-head"> <?php print $mainlevel4header ?></h4>
```

Problem I am having if I am putting links or anything other then text it breaks is there a better way to do this ?

For example

$contactcontent2 = "You will most likely get answered faster if you  href="https://site.com/support">Submit a Ticket</a> or use our 
`<a href="https://site.com/community/">Community Forums</a>`.";

Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear, do elaborate and provide a proper example of "links".

Comment: I noticed your comment. Consult [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22847755/) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

As per [`your comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847340/how-to-put-link-or-other-characters-in-print-php#comment34853959_22847618), use:

**Example 1:**

```
<?php

$mainlevel4header = "You will most likely get answered faster if you <a href=\"sitename.com/support\">Submit a Ticket</a> or use our <a href=\"sitename.com/community/\">Community Forums</a>.";

?>

<h4 class="total-solution-head"> <?php print $mainlevel4header ?></h4>
```

Or using single quotes if you don't want to escape the double quotes.

Escaping means to use `\"`

**Example 2:**

```
<?php

$mainlevel4header = 'You will most likely get answered faster if you <a href="sitename.com/support">Submit a Ticket</a> or use our <a href="sitename.com/community/">Community Forums</a>.';

?>

<h4 class="total-solution-head"> <?php print $mainlevel4header ?></h4>
```

***Sidenote:*** If you are going to use apostrophes in the second example, you will need to escape those.

For example: `What\'s happening`

---

#### Original answer

If I understood correctly, you can place hyperlinks.

Base yourself on the following:

```
<?php
$mainlevel4header = "http://www.example.com";
$mainlevel4header_2 = "WHAT'S DIFFERENT? ADDWEBTOUR";
?>

<h4 class="total-solution-head"> <?php print $mainlevel4header ?></h4>

<h1 class="total-solution-head"> <?php print "<a href=\"$mainlevel4header\">link to $mainlevel4header</a>"; ?></h1>

<h1 class="total-solution-head"> <?php print "<a href=\"$mainlevel4header\">Text from variable $mainlevel4header_2</a>"; ?></h1>
```

Which will echo with the 2nd and 3rd lines as a hyperlink:

`http://www.example.com`
`link to http://www.example.com`
`Text from variable WHAT'S DIFFERENT? ADDWEBTOUR`

Comment: Something like this $mainlevel4header = "You will most likely get answered faster if you <a href="https://sitename.com/support">Submit a Ticket</a> or use our <a href="https://sitename.com/community/">Community Forums</a>.";

Comment: Yes, see my first and second example. @user2530184 I used your example for them.

Comment: So, how are you making out, have you tried it? @user2530184

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about plain links like `http://www.domain.com` or HTML links like `<a href="http://www.domain.com/">Domain</a>`

Correct format for html links:

```
<?php $mainlevel4header = "WHAT'S DIFFERENT? <a href=\"http://www.domain.com\">Domain</a>";?>

<h4 class="total-solution-head"> <?php echo $mainlevel4header; ?></h4>
```

or

```
<?php $mainlevel4header = 'WHAT\'S DIFFERENT? <a href="http://www.domain.com">Domain</a>';?>

<h4 class="total-solution-head"> <?php echo $mainlevel4header; ?></h4>
```

Comment: Something like this $mainlevel4header = "You will most likely get answered faster if you  <a href="https://sitename.com/support">Submit a Ticket</a> or use our 
<a href="https://sitename.com/community/">Community Forums</a>.";

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `print()`. You should use `echo` instead.

It will allow you to use html format.

```
<h4 class="total-solution-head"> <?php echo $mainlevel4header; ?></h4>
```

Comment: I did not downvote this, by the way; it's not my style.